# Minecraft Graphics Suddenly turned Bad

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft for a few years on the same computer and suddenly the graphics have gone bad. I thought it was the 1.5 update and my crappy graphics card wasn't supported anymore but then I tried voltz (1.4.7) and it is exactly the same. Here is an example:

[image: Items are distorted]

My graphics card, like I said, is very old (Intel 82945g). But it has been running perfectly for ages. I've attempted installing a new texture pack (sphax 32x32) but this didn't help. It's not really the blocks that are the problem, just the items.

The texture pack shown is just the default Minecraft.

Comment: There was an update to Java released today. Perhaps that might have something to do with it? You could also go through the standard troubleshooting by updating your graphics card, clearing the Java cache, etc.

Comment: Nah I don't think so. I've had this issue for a while now and only cared for it now because I've started playing minecraft again. (By a while i mean after the 1.5 update)

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie I would recommend actually going into the item image files in the minecraft.jar and seeing how they look there. If they are broken in the files too, try forcing update on the launcher.

Comment: Is there some form of AA enabled on your GPU?

Comment: The Minecraft graphics were always bad </troll>

Comment: @Alex never this bad... Have you seen the image?

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie Yeah, and it does look like a video driver issue to me (Mojang would probably have tested the latest Java patch for compatibility).

Comment: Just updated my graphics driver (via windows update) and now I the game just closes straight away once logging in. Guess it's time to buy a new graphics card -_-.

Comment: Sounds like your graphics card was about to die. Good catch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buying a cheap $50(AU) graphics card completely solved the problem. The graphics card that I was using was an integrated graphics card (Intel 82945g) and despite me upgrading basically everything else in the computer, I hadn't upgraded the graphics card, because it worked for the games I was playing.

[image: Problem Solvered]

This is the result, and I can now play in far render with no lag! If you're graphics card is old, I suggest buying a new one. It literally makes your PC so much more enjoyable.